# Get value from list dict in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

**I have list of dict,**

```
result = {'lat': u'-7.798668', 'lng': u'110.369487', 'name': u'Kalimas Service', 'address': u'Jalan Mayor'}
```

**I want output :**

```
lat = -7.798668
lng = 110.369487
name = Kalimas Services
address = Jalan Mayor
```

please help me to this problems...!

Comment: Looks to me like you just have a dict. And "please help me to this problems" isn't a question; what have you tried?

Comment: What have you tried? You have to iterate over the dictionary and output the key and value. These are very basic operations. Have a look at the tutorial: http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries, http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print "lat = %s" %result['lat']
print "lng = %s" %result['lng']
print "name = %s" %result['name']
print 'address = %s' %result['address']
```

OR

```
for val in "lat lng name address".split():
    print "%s = %s" %(val, result[val])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use dict built_in method items()

```
    result = {'lat': u'-7.798668', 'lng': u'110.369487', 'name': u'Kalimas Service', 'address': u'Jalan Mayor'}
    for k, v in result.items():
      print k, "=", v
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for accessing a dict is like:

```
l = {'key': value}
l['key'] == value
```

To get the keys in a dict, use `dict.keys()`

Try using that to make the results you want.